# For a Jquery UI button how can I remove the blue glow on focus?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I am working with Jquery UI. I have a button that I have replaced with a background image. JQuery UI places a circular blow glow around the button on focus. I want to override the css such that the blue glow does not appear.

The markup looks like this:

```
<form id="sliderUIContainer" class="noUIeffects">
 <label for="slider-0" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Input Slider</label>
 <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider-0" value="0" min="0" max="20" />
</form>
```

What will I have to add to the CSS to override this effect?

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to remove the glow from *all* jQuery UI elements, I would suggest using the following code near the beginning of your CSS:

```
/* Disable jQuery UI focus glow */

*:focus {
    outline: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

This way, you will not need to track down each individual ui-focus selector (i.e. .ui-btn-focus, .ui-tabs-focus, .ui-accordion-focus..ect).

Answer (score 4):

For me, on chrome 26 for mac, I fixed this by changing "outline" to none.

(the other diff from Andy's answer is that my issue was on a ui-slider-handle rather than ui-btn):

```
.ui-slider-handle:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me in Safari and Chrome on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit the css I'm afraid:

```
.ui-focus,
.ui-btn:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much that did the trick, that was what I was looking for, the proper classes to override. If you do happen to read this response, is there some way that I could have known that. Where would I have gone to learn that?

Comment: You can inspect element in most browsers, each have their own way of implementing it. Lets assume you are using chrome, right click the element and select Inspect Element. Now you can find information about that element, including its ID and classes