# Stopping weird outline on checkbox check in table

Tags: html, css

I have a table using datatables that has a checkbox in one of the `th`'s. When I click on the checkbox, I get this:

[image]

I'm trying to remove this blue outline. Does anyone know how I would do this or what causes it?

Comment: Presumably you're using jquery UI? which has a focus definition. You can find the focus definition in css, and change the format. Or see this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606437/for-a-jquery-ui-button-how-can-i-remove-the-blue-glow-on-focus

Comment: Thank you, using `outline:none` on my `th` table worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style for the th element to disable outlines like so:
`th{outline:none;}`